# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&&'

Tags: javascript, syntax

this is my first attempt at JavaScript so be easy on me! I am having a heck of a time getting this script to work. I get the error in the title but can't seem to find how it affects me (other postings don't involve my situation or I simply don't understand them).

What's really confusing me is I'm not even getting the prompt in the second line to work!

```js
<script>
var chipQuant;
chipQuant = prompt("How many chips would you like to purchase?");
document.write("Number of chips purchased: " + chipQuant);
var unitCost;
unitCost = 110
document.write("Cost per unit: $" + unitCost)
var discount = "";
if (chipQuant > 0 && chipQuant <= 19) {
 discount = 0; }
  else if (chipQuant >= 20 && chipQuant <= 49) {
 discount = 0.02; }
  else if (chipQuant >= && chipQuant <= 79) {
 discount = 0.04; }
  else if (chipQuant >= && chipQuant <= 99) {
 discount = 0.06; }
  else { discount = 0.08; }
var subTotal;
subTotal = chipQuant x unitCost;
document.write("Total cost before discount: " + subTotal);
var discountAmt;
discountAmt = subTotal x discount;
document.write("Discount percentage/amount: " + discount + "/" discountAmt);
var total;
total = subTotal - discountAmt
document.write("Total cost after discount: " + total);
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `subTotal = chipQuant x unitCost;` ???

Comment: `chipQuant x unitCost` is not valid JavaScript. `*` is the multiplication operator. *"What's really confusing me is I'm not even getting the prompt in the second line to work!"* The program won't be executed if you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

`else if (chipQuant >= && chipQuant <= 79) {`

line 13... you didn't give any value.

EDIT: **Please check the browser console for errors next time. It will show you such an error with exact line where it occurs.**

Comment: Typo questions should not be answered, there is a close vote reason specifically for them.

Comment: I don't see what the error is. I actually did find the * issue but forgot to correct. thanks

Comment: @PatrickEvans It's not a typo... the person answered the question doesn't know what they're doing yet.

Comment: @freeyourminde: `chipQuant >= &&` is missing a value between `>=` and `&&`. You cannot compare `chipQuant` to `&&` that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PatrickEvans and who said that? you? give me a rule in terms and conditions of StackOverflow that says that.

Comment: oh jeez, the value...**shame**

Comment: Here goes the "should typo questions be answered" debate again.

Comment: are there chats we can use instead of starting threads? I try to never post, knowing I'm a beginner and the issue is probably silly...

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes, but it's a good practice to check console for errors ... it will give you the line and you probably would notice it yourself.

Comment: **1.** Typo questions' answers are usually simple and straightforward that only a comment will suffice to point out and fix the error. **2.** There is a close category for typo questions. AFAIK, closed questions should not be answered (except in some cases).

Comment: Link to that? I can't find it. Or is it your interpretation? I'm not here to gain easy points, I'm here to help. If there is a real rule that says that I shouldn't do that that way, I will delete my answer.

Comment: @FlashThunder That's why the **AFAIK** is there for.

Comment: Ok :-) I got it.

Comment: I did use the console but simply failed to notice the missing value. I think I just need more practice reading code. Thanks all and sorry for the useless post

Comment: It's ok... Everyone is a rookie at start. Nothing to be ashamed of. I'm trying to help both sides. And to point out a way to learn new things.